# Mongodb implementation procedure after database design

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, database-design, pojo

I finished the initial database design as follows: I have a collection that follows embedded document structure with an uid, timestamp and deivce data as fields. device data is the embedded document that has different variable fields.
My question here is whats next? what should i do to enable the android app to insert data into these collections? someone told me to define a POJO, i did. I am not sure what and how the next steps are to build the database? if someone can help me with the procedure, atleast then i can figure out how i can follow those steps and finish the development.

I am a beginner, kindly request you to help me!Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to start with this doc: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/driver/